# I don't understand the output of this code.

Tags: java, constructor

Q. The following is my code, but I don't understand the output. I thought the output should be 
11
3
3.14159
11
8
3.14159 
but the output is totally different from what I expected.

public class Time {

```
    private int hour; 
    private int minute; 
    private double second; 

    public Time () { 
        this. hour = 0; 
        this.minute = 0;
        this.second = 0;
    }
    public Time ( int hour, int minute, double second ) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  // one way to create and initialize a Time object
  Time t1 = new Time ();
  t1. hour = 11; 
  t1. minute = 3; 
  t1. second= 3.14159; 
  System.out.println(t1);

  // another way to do the same thing
  Time t2 = new Time ( 11, 8, 3.14159); 
  System.out.println (t2);
}
```

}

**The actual output :   Time@7852e922
               Time@4e25154f

Comment: You will need to make a toString method, so it knows how to print the data.